# sharp ratio/sortino ratio for options portfolio

Tags: sharpe-ratio, option-strategies

I am thinking that the sharp ratio is not a valid performance metric for a long/short options book, because options are inherently nonlinear and the standard deviation simply cannot correctly capture the risk.

What do you think?

Comment: I think it is generally agreed that Sharpe Ratio is not appropriate for option portfolios. It can give misleading results. Will Goetzmann of Yale, among others, has written about this.

Comment: @AlexC do they suggest any alternative? I'm thinking about the Greeks etc but unsure.